# How to pass argument to delegate method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, activemodel, presenter

I would like to have a Dashboard to display summary of multiple models, and I implemented it using Presenter without its own data. I use an ActiveModel class (without data table):

```
class Dashboard
  attr_accessor :user_id
  def initialize(id)
    self.user_id = id
  end

  delegate :username, :password, :to => :user 
  delegate :address,  :to => :account
  delegate :friends,   :to => :friendship

end
```

By delegate, I want to be able to call `Dashboard.address` and get back `Account.find_by_user_id(Dashboard.user_id).address`.

If Dashboard was an ActiveRecord class, then I could have declared `Dashboard#belongs_to :account` and delegate would work automatically (i.e., Account would know it should return address attribute from account with `user_id` equals `to user_id` in Dashboard instance).

But Dashboard is not an ActiveRecord class, so I can't declare `belongs_to`. I need another way to tell Account to lookup the right record.

Is there a way to overcome this problem? (I know I can fake Dashboard to have an empty table, or I can rewrite User's instance methods to class methods that take argument. But these solutions are all hacks).

Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. What is `id`? Is that supposed to be a number? (You can't `send("123")`, that's not a valid method name.) You can't use `Dashboard.user_id` with `attr_accessor :user_id`, one is a class and the other is the instance... Please clarify and give examples of how you expect this to work.

Comment: Hi Andy, may be I am not clear enough. Please note that this is not a regular ActiveRecord::Base class. Therefore, I need an attribute to hold id of the current_user. (I don't want to keep this id permanently though). By delegate, I want to be able to call Dashboard.address and get back Account.find_by_user_id(Dashboard.user_id).address. I attempted to delegate this function to Account class, but I need to pass user_id value to Account somehow, so that it knows which account instance it should work with.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you write `delegate :address, :to => :account`, this creates a new `address` method on Dashboard which basically calls the `account` method on the same object and then calls `address` on the result of this `account` method. This is (very roughly) akin to writing:

```
class Dashboard
 ...
  def address
    self.account.address
  end
 ...
end
```

With your current class, all you have to do is to create an `account` method which returns the account with the correct `user_id`:

```
class Dashboard
  attr_accessor :user_id
  def initialize(id)
    self.user_id = id
  end

  delegate :username, :password, :to => :user 
  delegate :address,  :to => :account
  delegate :friends,   :to => :friendship

  def account
    @account ||= Account.find_by_user_id(self.user_id)
  end
end
```

This would allow you to access the address like this:

```
dashboard = Dashboard.new(1)
# the following returns Account.find_by_user_id(1).address
address = dashboard.address
```

Comment: @AdamNYC Do not hesitate to ask for clarifications if you have any doubts about the above code, I'll gladly put additional explanations.